# How can I add array elements in method?

Tags: java, arrays, sum

I have to input three array elements and then a method should calculate them and return the answer. I only have this :

```
boolean answer = false;   

final int ARRAY_SIZE = 3;
 int sum[] = new int [ARRAY_SIZE];

 for(int i = 0; i<sum.length;i++){

 sum[i]= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number"));    

 }

 answer = one(sum);

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The sum of the elements is "+answer);
}  
public static boolean one(int[] nums){return(nums[0] + nums[1] + nums[2]);}

}
```

Comment: And what is your question or problem?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you are returning a `boolean` from your `one` method. You should be returning an `int`.

Comment: I see, didn't even think of it.. Still loads to learn. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my improvements will help you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int ARRAY_SIZE = 3;
    int sum[] = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < sum.length; i++) {

        sum[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number"));

    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The sum of the elements is " + one(sum));
}

public static int one(int[] nums) {
    return (nums[0] + nums[1] + nums[2]);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, I can see my mistake now. Thank you :)